# JS Canvas : Identifier 'Blob' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

I work on JS with the canvas to create signature, I declare the class "blob" class that previously called "Signature", however it tells me that my variable, no matter what its name, is already identified in the code, and guess what ... It's impossible, it's already declared !

```js
window.onload =() => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');  
    script.src =  "Script.js";
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
}
class Blob {
    constructor(canvas) {
        this.sign = false
        this.prevX = 0
        this.prevY = 0
        this.canvas = document.querySelector(canvas)
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = "violet"
        this.ctx.lineWidth = 2
        console.log(this.canvas)

        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
            this.sign = true
            console.log(e)
            this.prevX = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft
            this.prevY = e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop
        });
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            if (this.sign) {
                let currX = e.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft
                let currY = e.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop
                this.draw(this.prevX, this.prevY, currX, currY)
                this.prevX = currX
                this.prevY = currY
            }
        });
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
            this.sign = false
        });
        this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
            this.sign = false
        });
    }
    draw(depX, depY, destX, destY) {
        this.ctx.beginPath()
        this.ctx.moveTo(depX, depY)
        this.ctx.lineTo(destX, destY)
        this.ctx.closePath()
        this.ctx.stroke()
    }
    effacer() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height)
    }
    genererImage() {
        const MySign = this.canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream")
        document.getElementById("mySign").innerHTML = MySign;
        return document.getElementById("RSign");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Signature</title>
    <center>
      <img src="logoTCS2tier.png" width="191" height="116" />
      <style>
        canvas {
          border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        }
        button {
          background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #4e96ba, #093d7d);
          border: black;
          color: white;
          padding: 11px 24px;
        }
      </style>
    </center>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <script src="Signature.js"></script>
      <form
        action="UploadBlob.php"
        value="submit"
        method="GET"
        onsubmit="return genererImage()">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Formulaire de Signature</legend>
          <pre>nom                     prénom</pre>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Entrez un Nom ici" id="nom" />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Entrez un Prénom ici"x
            id="Pnom"
          /><br /><br />
          <script src="Signature.js"></script>
          <canvas id="Blob" width="300" height="300"></canvas><br />
          <button type="submit" href="#" id="Signature"><span id="mySign">Signé</button>
          <hr />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
      <button href="#" id="effacer">Effacer</button>
      <hr />
    </center>
    <button id="afficher" onclick="afficher()">Afficher</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Merci d'avance pour votre retours.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error thrown when the code is run? Could you add that to your post? That way it is easier to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's already a global [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) class on browsers, so you'll have to do one of two things:

1. Use a different name. Or,
2. Put your code in a [*module*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) (`script type="module"`), so that top-level declarations don't create globals (thus avoiding the conflict; `Blob` would only refer to your class within the module). All modern browsers support modules.

(A variation on #2 is to wrap all your code in an inline-invoked function expression [IIFE], but in modern environments, there's no need for that; just use modules.)

Comment: thank you for your answer !
So I changed my class to "Signature" and I import it this way: 
<script type="module" src="Signature.js"></script>
now i can't draw my signature, it could be that wordpress can't handle the canvas?
ps:
wordpress, never let me sign, however when I host the page locally via devserv, it works fine

Comment: @Kromoss_ - If you rename the class (#1), you don't have to use a module (#2), although using modules is useful for other reasons. If you look in the devtools console on the browser, you'll see that  it's complaining about your module `src` path. As it says in the [MDN modules documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) I linked, when referring to a module file in the same directory, you have to use the `./` prefix: `src="./signature.js"` so it's not a "bare" specifier, since those are going to be used by import maps and such.